# What keyboard/mouse actions can wake up Windows 7 from sleep mode

Tags: windows-7

I have a Lenovo T420, Windows 7 Home. What keyboard/mouse actions can wake up Windows from sleep mode? Does this apply to all Windows 7 or varies with Windows 7 version (home/professional) or even the laptop model?

I found moving mouse/clicking mouse/hit left ctrl key can wake up Windows. Want to know the full list.

Comment: Yeah, it is going to depend entirely on your drivers and BIOS. But thankfully, there are some of those settings you can change from Windows without having to reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Waking up has nothing to do with Windows. It is not running in the sleep state. The BIOS has settings for wake-up, usually. Some allow changing settings while others only allow enabling and disabling.